# Pasar parametro a sp desde c# ncapas

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure

Hola a todos soy nuevo en el foro y quisiera me pudiesen ayudar con este problema:

Tengo el siguiente sp en SQlServer:

```
        @idNombre int=0
AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT roles.rol as Roles, permisos.permiso as Per,
    modulos.Idmodulo as IdMod, modulos.modnom as Nom
    FROM permisos 
INNER JOIN
    roles ON permisos.idpermit = roles.idrol 
INNER JOIN
    modulos ON roles.idModulo = modulos.IdModulo
    WHERE modulos.IdModulo = @idNombre--Esta variable debe recibir el parametro (Id) selecionado en el combobox.

END
```

Desde C# con un combo quiero enviar el Id del modulo a filtrar en un dgv.

La aplicación la estoy desarrollando en C# con programación por capas, estos son mis métodos:

Sigo recibiendo el mismo error:
**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function Modulos has too many arguments specified.'**

Agrego todo el código tal como lo tengo en C#, solo implemente el uso de using y el Try Catch en la carga del dgv.

Clases Acceso a Datos:
Método para cargar el comboBox:

```
namespace CapaDAO
{
    public class CDAO_Nombres
    {
        private CDAO_Conexion conexion = new CDAO_Conexion();

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        public DataTable mostrarNombres()
        {
            cmd.Connection = conexion.OpenConexion();
            cmd.CommandText = "Nombres";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (read.HasRows)
                {
                    tbl.Load(read);
                }
                conexion.CloseConexion();
                return tbl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Método para cargar el DataGridView:

```
namespace CapaDAO
{
    public class CDAO_Modulos
    {
        private CDAO_Conexion conexion = new CDAO_Conexion();

        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        int idnombre;

        public DataTable mostrarModulos()
        {
            cmd.Connection = conexion.OpenConexion();
            cmd.CommandText = "Modulos";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idNombre", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@idNombre"].Value = idnombre;
            using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (read.HasRows)
                {
                    tbl.Load(read);
                }
                conexion.CloseConexion();
                return tbl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Métodos de la capa de negocio:

```
namespace CapaBo
{
    public class CBO_Nombres
    {
        private CDAO_Nombres objectCD = new CDAO_Nombres();
        public DataTable listarNombres()
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl = objectCD.mostrarNombres();
            return tbl;

        }
    }
}


namespace CapaBo

{
    public class CBO_Modulos
    {
        private CDAO_Modulos objectCD = new CDAO_Modulos();
        public DataTable listarModulos()
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            tbl = objectCD.mostrarModulos();
            return tbl;
        }
    }
}
```

Capa de presentación:

```
namespace Softecm
{
    public partial class frmModulos: Form
    {
        CBO_Nombres objectCD = new CBO_Nombres();
        CBO_Modulos objectCDM = new CBO_Modulos();


        public frmActivities()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmActivities_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listaNom();
            listaMod();
        }

       

        private void listaNom()
        {
            cmbApp.DataSource = objectCD.listarNombres();
            cmbApp.DisplayMember = "nommod";
            cmbApp.ValueMember = "idnombre";
        }

        private void listaMod()
        {
                dgv.DataSource = objectCDM.listarModulos();
        }

        private void cmbApp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cmbApp.SelectedIndex != 0)
                    listaMod();
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo cargar el dgv: " + error.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111362/discussion-on-question-by-erickgamer-pasar-parametro-a-sp-desde-c-ncapas).

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias por el comentario y lo entiendo pero me puedes referir algún enlace donde explique como pasar de los comentarios a un chat. En dias pasados, trabajando en otra respuesta la plataforma creó un chat automaticamente pero esta vez no fue así.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez cuando hay muchos comentarios, al tratar de agregar uno nuevo aparece un link que ofrece pasar la conversacion a un chat. Solo los moderadores diamantados pueden pasar los comentarios a un chat y borrarlos de la publicación, aunque cada uno puede tambien borrar sus propios comentarios...

Comment: @gbianchi. Entiendo, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nuevo error que mencionas no se corresponde con el código que para este momento tienes publicado en la pregunta. Asegurate que en tu código actual no estás agreando el parámmetro mas de una vez.

El problema original ocurre porque tu StoredProcedure requere que le envíes el parámetro `@idNombre` pero con la línea `cmd.Parameters.Add("@idNombre", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output` estás diciendo que el Store Procedure te lo devuelve como una respuesta.

Si tuviera que modificar tu método `mostrarModulos` para hacerlo funcionar, haría lo siguiente:

**Actualización**

Luego de la actualización en el código de tu pregunta y un largo intercambio de comentarios, pude notar que el problema está en la reutilización del `SqlCommand`.

En la primera invocación, el método se ejecuta sin problemas, pero es a partir de la segunda que se produce el error y es porque cada invocación agrega el parámetro al mismo SqlCommand.

Ten en cuenta que al corregir la exception vas a tener otro problema con el filtro porque la variable `idnombre` nunca recibe un valor externo y siempre tendrá `0`.

Mi sugerencia es que pases ese valor como parámetro al método `mostrarModulos()`

Con toda esta nueva información y ahora que tengo acceso al código de la clase completa, estos serían los cambios:

```
public class CDAO_Modulos
{
    private CDAO_Conexion conexion = new CDAO_Conexion();

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    // Elimino la declaración del SqlCommand de aquí


    // Esta variable nunca la inicializas y tampoco recibe un valor externo
    // sugiero eliminar esta declaración y agregarla como parámetro al método
    // mostrarModulos().
    int idnombre;


    // En el método mostrarModulos, sugiero agregar idnombre como parámetro 
    // Su firma quedaría así:
    //         public DataTable mostrarModulos(int idnombre)
    // y tendrías que modificar todas las invocaciones para pasarle un valor
    public DataTable mostrarModulos()
    {
        // La declaración del SqlCommand anteriormente eliminada
        // ahora se utiliza dentro de un bloque using
        // para que el framework se encargue de descartarla apropiadamente.
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conexion.OpenConexion();
            cmd.CommandText = "Modulos";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idNombre", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@idNombre"].Value = idnombre;
            using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (read.HasRows)
                {
                    tbl.Load(read);
                }
                conexion.CloseConexion();
                return tbl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que en este código no incluyo manejo de excepciones, te invito a investigar un poco más al respecto para que puedas incorporarlo a tu programa. (más abajo encontrarás enlaces a lo que puede ser un punto de partida)

Aquí continúa la información de mi respuesta original...

En cuanto al error del `DataReader` abierto, es seguro que no tiene que ver con que los métodos estén en la misma clase, se puede ver el uso de una variable llamada `read` pero no podemos ver dónde está declarada y cuanto lo usas en el flujo del programa. Aunque la cierres en el método, nada garantiza que no viene abierta de otra parte.

Ten en cuenta que el uso de variables globales (como `cmd`, `read`, `idnombre`, `tbl`) hacen muy dificil la comprensión del código, lo hacen propenso a errores y en general pueden producir muchas complicaciones dificiles de descubrir y resolver.

Aunque en el código que publicaste no se observa [manejo de excepciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally) ni que estés descartando (Dispose) los objetos que implementan la interface [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netcore-3.1#remarks), espero que lo estés manejando en otra parte de tu programa y si no fuera así, ten en cuenta que debes hacerlo.

Espero que me cuentes como te va y si se te encuentras con otro error, edita la pregunta para colocar el código exactamente como está para ese momento y enviame un comentario para revisarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, por la ayuda que me estas brindando lo agradezco.
Hice los cambios que comentaste e hice el uso de using en los dos métodos, con esto no veo que se cierre el Datareader cuando tenia los métodos en la misma clase los cerraba así: read.Close(); y me marcaba el error que tenia abierto un Datareader cuando pretendía cargarlo. Separe los métodos en dos clases y dejo de marcarme ese error, ahora el error que sigue persistiendo pese a los cambios hechos es "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function Modulos has too many arguments specified.' @Pablo Gutiérrez